# Peer not able to join channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

```
    Organizations:
      - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrderingService
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/reliance-network.com/msp

      - &RelianceCapital
        Name: RelianceCapitalMSP
        ID: RelianceCapitalMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/reliancecapital.reliance-network.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.reliancecapital.reliance-network.com
            Port: 7051

      - &RelianceCommunications
        Name: RelianceCommunicationsMSP
        ID: RelianceCommunicationsMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/reliancecommunications.reliance-network.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.reliancecommunications.reliance-network.com
            Port: 9051

      - &RelianceEntertainment
        Name: RelianceEntertainmentMSP
        ID: RelianceEntertainmentMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/relianceentertainment.reliance-network.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.relianceentertainment.reliance-network.com
            Port: 11051

      - &RelianceInfrastructure
        Name: RelianceInfrastructureMSP
        ID: RelianceInfrastructureMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/relianceinfrastructure.reliance-network.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.relianceinfrastructure.reliance-network.com
            Port: 13051

      - &ReliancePower
        Name: ReliancePowerMSP
        ID: ReliancePowerMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/reliancepower.reliance-network.com/msp
        AnchorPeers:
          - Host: peer0.reliancepower.reliance-network.com
            Port: 15051
    #Capabilities

    Capabilities:
      Global: &ChannelCapabilities
        V1_3: true
      Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V1_1: true
      Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V1_3: true

    #Application

    Application: &ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:

    #Orderer
    Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

      OrdererType: solo
      Addresses:
        - orderer.reliance-network.com:7050
      BatchTimeout: 5s
      BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 256 MB
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB
      Kafka:
        Brokers: 
          - 127.0.0.1:9092

      Organizations:



    #Profiles
    Profiles:
        OrdererGenesis:
          Capabilities:
            <<: *ChannelCapabilities
          Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
              - *OrdererOrg
            Capabilities:
              <<: *OrdererCapabilities
          Consortiums:
            RelianceConsortium:
              Organizations:
                - *RelianceCapital
                - *RelianceCommunications
                - *RelianceEntertainment
                - *RelianceInfrastructure
                - *ReliancePower
        RelianceOrgs:
          Consortium: RelianceConsortium
          Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
              - *RelianceCapital
              - *RelianceCommunications
              - *RelianceEntertainment
              - *RelianceInfrastructure
              - *ReliancePower
            Capabilities:
              <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

<!-- end snippet -->
```

I am trying to create a network with 5 orgs.

1)Able to successfully create the crypto-config files
2) Channel artifacts are created successfully
3) Channel transaction is created successfully
4) Anchor peer transactions are created successfully
5) Created channel successfully
6) peer 0 of the first org is able to join the channel

But when peer 1 of first is trying to join the channel, getting the below error. What can be the reason.

******Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer1.reliancecapital.reliance-network.com:8051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 192.168.64.12:8051: connect: connection refused"******

Comment: Can you paste your configtx.yaml file? It seems its some mismatch of port configuration.

Comment: added the configtx.yaml file. Please look

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but you seem to have a DNS resolution problem on your hands. If you're launching this setup via docker-composer, then you might want to modify your `/etc/host` to route requests for `peer1.reliancecapital.reliance-network.com` to your localhost.

You can also statically bind `peer1.reliancecapital.reliance-network.com` to your machine's IP via the `extra_hosts` option in your docker-compose file. Also make sure that all your peers are in the same docker network.